# Deriving the function does not get the desired form

Tags: differential-equations

```
Clear[Evaluate[$Context <> "*"]];
Clear["Global`*"];
ClearAll;
x' = fx[t] + u[t];
e = xd[t] - x[t];
u = k e + xd'[t] + 1/epson rou^2 e;
V = 0.5 e^2;
D[V, t] // FullSimplify
```

The form I want is:

[image]

So how can I get the form?

Comment: you can at least get rid of the superfluous 1.'s by replacing the machine-precision number in your expression with an exact number, i.e., changing 0.5 to 1/2

Comment: You have to define your functions consistently: either with or without arguments. Your code uses inconsistent definitions. For example, `x' = ...` should be `x'[t_] := ...` if it's supposed to be a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with obtaining the desired expression is that it contains `xd'[t] + ... -xd'[t]` and those two terms are going to cancel.  Another problem is that Mathematica will expand your expression, so it won't have the desired form exactly, but this is close:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
e = xd[t] - x[t];
v = 1/2 e^2;
u = k e + xd'[t] + 1/epson rou^2 e;
D[v, t] /. x'[t] -> fx[t] + u 

(**   (-x[t] + xd[t])*
      (-fx[t] - k*(-x[t] + xd[t]) - 
        (rou^2*(-x[t] + xd[t])) / epson)   **)
```